# How to get total object value when we filter child object

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I am new for mulesfot and I want to filter below payload total object when characters[].data[] array "name": "priority" and "value": 1

Can some one help me please?.

**json payload**

--

```
{
  "offers": [
    {
      "id": 100,
      "name": "Test1",
      "category": {
        "characters": [
          {
            "data": [
              {
                "name": "priority",
                "value": 1
              },
              {
                "type": "ILL",
                "result": "pass"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 200,
      "name": "Test2",
      "category": {
        "characters": [
          {
            "data": [
              {
                "name": "priority",
                "value": 2
              },
              {
                "type": "ILL",
                "result": "Fail"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 300,
      "name": "Test3",
      "category": {
        "characters": [
          {
            "data": [
              {
                "name": "priority",
                "value": 3
              },
              {
                "type": "ILL",
                "result": "Pass"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Expected result**

--

```
{
      "id": 100,
      "name": "Test1",
      "category": {
        "characters": [
          {
            "data": [
              {
                "name": "priority",
                "value": 1
              },
              {
                "type": "ILL",
                "result": "pass"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

**Below code i tried but not suitable to my requirement**

--

```
(payload.offers map {
    (($$): $) if((flatten($.category.characters.data) filter ((item, index) -> item.name=="WBB" and item.priority==1)))
}) - {}
```

Comment: Can there be multiple instances of name WBB and priority 1?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply filter for nested arrays in mulesoft dataWeave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73710764/how-to-apply-filter-for-nested-arrays-in-mulesoft-dataweave)

Answer (score 1):

If multiple instances of name ="WBB" and priority = 1 doesn't exist , the following can get you to your goal

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var interim = (payload.offers  map {
    (($$): "true") if((flatten($.category.characters.data).name contains "priority") and (flatten($.category.characters.data).value contains 1))
}) - {}
---
payload.offers[(1 - sizeOf(interim))]
```

if you happen to have multiple sections with name=priority and value 1 then you could use the below modified version (this will return an array of objects)

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var interim = (payload.offers  map {
    (($$): "true") if((flatten($.category.characters.data).name contains "priority") and (flatten($.category.characters.data).value contains 1))
}) - {}
---
interim map {
       a: payload.offers[($$)]
}.a
```

Comment: Hi @Salim khan  i have edited my question , Can you please check once?

Comment: my json payload can contains multiple instances of  name= "priority" and value 1

Comment: I have updated my json payload as well as expected payload

Comment: you changed your ask quite a bit.

Comment: Your input contains only instance of name="priority" and value=1